# Accessing properties of object/cursor returned from .find and .forEach in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

changed schema and everything went crazy (see changes below). now accessing properties from .find() and cursor.forEach() is returning 'undefined' in backend:

EDIT: have found

```
.find().lean().exec(callback)
```

allows access to properties in callback but hard to do anything with them and that to access properties by doing

```
doc._doc.property
```

works in callbacks:

```
.find(function(err,doc){for (i in docs){doc=docs[i]; console.log(doc._doc.property)}} 
and .forEach(function(doc){console.log(doc._doc.property)}:
```

My schema once looked like this

for collection of people

```
{
  name: String,
  v: Types.ObjectId, ref: V //shorthand
  r: {
    e: [{}], 
    u: [{}]  
  }
}
```

now it looks like this

```
var people = new mongoose.Schema (
 {
  name: String,
  v: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: V} 
  r: {
    e: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: R}], 
    u: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: R}]  
   }
 }
)
mongoose.model('people',people);
```

for collection of r

```
var collR = new mongoose.Schema({}, {strict:false})
mongoose.model('R',collR)
```

nodejs controller 1:

```
module.exports.getProducts = function (req, res) {

 people.find(req.query)
  .populate('v r.e r.u')
  .exec(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {sendJsonResponse(res,400,err)} 
      else {
       data.forEach(function(single){
         single.r.e.forEach(function(sing){
          console.log(sing) //defined, and i saw rating, and its defined
          console.log(sing.rating); //undefined
          // do something with sing.rating but it's undefined here
          })
       })

     sendJsonResponse(res,200,data);   //not undefined on frontend success callback
     }
});


};
```

node controller 2:

```
    module.exports.getProducts = function (req, res) {

 people.find(req.query)
  .populate('v r.e r.u')
  .exec(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {sendJsonResponse(res,400,err)} 
      else {
       data.forEach(function(single){
        R.find({person: single.name}, function (err, dat) {
         dat.forEach(function(sing){
          console.log(sing) //defined and rating defined
          console.log(sing.rating);  //undefined ugh.
          //do something with rating but cant bc undefined here
          })
        })
       })

      //if i send data back here, in success callback, data[i].r.e[j].rating is defined for all i and j, whaaa!?!
     }
});


};
```

one of the sing's logged from the cursor.forEach loop---

```
{_id: 1254357653, name: peep, rating: 6, type: some type}
```

EDIT:

ya so:

```
collection.find(query).exec(function(err,docs) {
     docs.forEach(function(singleDoc) {
        console.log(singleDoc._doc.property); //DEFINED, bad boyz 4 lyfe *_*
   })
})
```

so i finally decided to console.log the darn keys of the document returned from a cursor.forEach

this also returns defined:

```
 collection.find(query).lean().exec(function(err,docs) {
 console.log(docs[i].property); //for all i, THEY'RE DEFINED!!!!! wooo
})
```

well now another issue pops up when i try to do an update inside a find

```
    collection.find(query).exec(function(err,docs) {
      if (err) {return errorHandler(err)};
      var doc = docs[0];
      var captainKeyes = Object.keys(req.body);
      for (k = 0 ; k < captainKeyes.length ; k++) {
        //update the doc key/value pairs with what is sent in req.body
        doc._doc[captainKeyes[k]] = req.body[captainKeyes[k]];
       //from above, learned to access properties captainKeyes[k], you have to first access
      //the hidden property _doc to get to actual doc

      }
      doc.save()  
       //old doc is still in db, damn. and all this used to work before 
       //we added that R collection :(
})
```

Comment: Can you share sample output for `console.log(sing)`?

Comment: sing is a document from the r.e path or in the new schema from the R collection, when the collection is made: {_id: 1254357653, name: peep, rating: 6, type: some type} (one is logged for the length of the dat array). when the R collection is not made, as in my first schema design, sing is the same except no _id field.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the schema for the collection R to have some keys, changing it from just an empty object with strict: false.

```
from {{},strict:false} to {{name: String, rating: Number, person: String},strict:false}
```

now i dont have to use _doc, wooohoooo, and all the queries works normally again.

moral of the story, i didn't really understand how to implement a schemaless collection properly, and then stuff got cray